# react-admin customer iteration for lists

Tags: react-admin

In React Admin, I follow the tutorial to build a [custom iterator for lists](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ListTutorial.html#building-a-custom-iterator):

```
import {List, TopToolbar, CreateButton, useListContext} from 'react-admin';
import {Challenge} from "../types";
import {Typography} from "@mui/material";

const ListActions = () => (
    <TopToolbar>
        <CreateButton />
    </TopToolbar>
);

const ChallengesListContent = (): JSX.Element[] => {
    const {
        data: challenges
    } = useListContext<Challenge>()

    return (
        challenges.map(challenge => (
           <Typography key={challenge.id}>
               <span>{challenge.title}</span>
           </Typography>
        )));
}

const ChallengesList = () => {
    return (
        <List actions={<ListActions/>}>
            <ChallengesListContent />
        </List>
    )
}

export default ChallengesList;
```

Now, I get a Typescript error saying `TS2786: 'ChallengesListContent' cannot be used as a JSX component.   Its return type 'Element[]' is not a valid JSX element.     Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key`

I tried following the example in the [CRM demo](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/examples/crm), but the [ContactList example](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/crm/src/contacts/ContactList.tsx) is quite complex and I ran into a few other issues. So I tried to simplify my markup substantially and follow the tutorial as closely as possible, to no avail.

Obviously I need to supply some additional attributes/properties, but I don't know how, because it never states in any tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the result in a JSX fragment:

```
import {List, TopToolbar, CreateButton, useListContext} from 'react-admin';
import {Challenge} from "../types";
import {Typography} from "@mui/material";

const ListActions = () => (
    <TopToolbar>
        <CreateButton />
    </TopToolbar>
);

const ChallengesListContent = (): JSX.Element => {
    const {
        data: challenges
    } = useListContext<Challenge>()

    return
      (<>{
        challenges.map(challenge => (
           <Typography key={challenge.id}>
               <span>{challenge.title}</span>
           </Typography>
        ))
      }</>);
}

const ChallengesList = () => {
    return (
        <List actions={<ListActions/>}>
            <ChallengesListContent />
        </List>
    )
}

export default ChallengesList;
```